# Is there a way to set multiple layer filters in the Mapbox Static Images API?

Tags: mapbox

I am using the [mapbox static images API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#static-images). I have two layers in my style that I'm trying to filter on the request. The documentation seems to only provide a single "setfilter" and a single "layer_id" property, indicating I can only filter one of the layers.

Is it possible to filter two (or three, four) layers in the static images API? I'd love to be able to comma separate the layer_id and/or setfilter parameters in the request to handle this case.

An example request they provide in the docs for setting the filters is:

```
https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/static/-91,60,2/800x600?access_token=YOUR_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN&setfilter=["==","name_en","Canada"]&layer_id=country-label
```

I am looking for something like:

```
https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/static/-91,60,2/800x600?access_token=YOUR_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN&setfilters=["==","name_en","Canada"],["==","name","New York"]&layer_ids=country-label,state-label
```

FWIW, my current workaround is to use an overlay for one of the layers to form the geojson objects that I needed filtering, but its hacky and has an upperbound on how many I can add to the request, and I had to simplify the geojson for brevity in the request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not a direct way to reference multiple layers in a request to the Static Images API.

As a workaround you may be able to create a new style layer in Mapbox Studio that combines all of the layers you want to apply a filter to. You could then use [setfilter](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/filter/) on that layer to achieve filtering across these multiple layers, see the [documentation here](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#style-parameters).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. The two specific layers I want to filter have two separate datasets and the use case calls for setting the background of the polygons to different colors. I don't see a way to do that in one layer on Mapbox, but I'm open to this idea!